# jQuery ajax returning 404 error when passing URL as post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have been getting a 404 error when using `$.ajax` and have narrowed it down to the problem being with one of the values I am passing with data.

I am trying to pass a url as text to be saved to my database.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {'edit-username': username, 'website-value': websiteValue}
}).done(function(){
    //custom code here
});
```

If I set `websiteValue` equal to http://google.com, Then I get a 404 error on chromes network tab. (this is true for anything other than my own domain.)

If I set it to //google.com or just google.com it works fine.

If I set it to http://mydomain.com it also works great.

I can't figure this one out and any help would be greatly appreciated. The ajax calls are being done over https if that makes any difference.

The ajax.php file does the following with the data.

```
$mysqli = connect_db();
$query = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE tbl SET website = ? WHERE username = ?');
$query->bind_param('ss', $website, $username);
$query->execute();
$query->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Try using "http ://localhost/"

Comment: @N20084753 That also results in a 404 error.

Comment: On the network tab, what is the full url for the failing requests?

Comment: Have you checked apache rewrite rule? How are you sending raw data? Is this url-encoded?

Comment: I would put up proxy or network tracing tool to see what request is causing the 404.

Comment: did u try doing encodeURIComponent(websiteValue)?

Comment: I would recommend "Fiddler"

Comment: @pradeep I just tried encodeURIComponent with no luck.

Comment: @BlakePlumb - this may be due to crossdomain ajax request issue, but i can't figure what's the problem when sending it in post data.

Comment: @N20084753 you just sending a string, i dont see it as harmful.

Comment: what is the type of websiteValue? Also can you try your URL as /ajax.php or the full relative URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is server response. Server try to prevent cross-domain attack. What is in server logs? What is the server?

Comment: I tested it on other pages, and our application firewall appears to not allow urls to be passed. I'll have to work with security on this.