# jQuery POST 404 not found issue due to http://

Tags: jquery

I have this script, I have no issue to add to cart in my local development machine.

in the Customization Link: * textbox, I need to pass a full URL. e.g
http://www.google.com

In local machine, I have not issue to add to cart, but in this live server, in inspect show that POST 404 not found.

However, if I remove the **http://** in the text box, it is able to add to cart. (e.g www.google.com)

Anyone what wrong with the server or the script problem?

The only part to catch the clink is below code:

```
var clink = getParameterByName('clink');
if(clink != '')
{
    $("div.options input[name^='option']").val(clink);
}

   //get query string value 
function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Now the problem is the ajax add to cart is not working if the input with http://, if you run in inspect mode, u can see POST 404 error. Other page does not have this issue.

Local Server:
OS: Windows
PHP: 5.4.36
Apache: 2.4.10
mySql: 5.5.40

Production Server:
OS: Linux (cPanel)
Apache Version  2.2.29
PHP Version 5.3.29
MySQL Version   5.5.42-cll
Architecture    x86_64
Operating System    linux

ajax for add to cart

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#product-main input[type=\'text\'], #product-main input[type=\'hidden\'], #product-main input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product-main input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product-main select, #product-main textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }

                if (json['error']['profile']) {
                    $('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>');
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                addProductNotice(json['title'], json['thumb'], json['success'], 'success');
                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']); 
                $('#cart_content').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart_content > *');
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Set the header for the Content-type: application/json on server side. Still not working.

Comment: Please dump the code that makes treatments to that `Customization link`. We're not here to inspect the full source code of your live website to find out what's going on.

Comment: @D4v1D Ya, now the problem is not on the specific code. The same code run in local environment no issue. Am suspecting is server issue or jquery issue.

Comment: So give us information on both your `dev` and `prod` server then.

Comment: added server info. From your experience, it is more to server or script problem?

Comment: Can we have the Ajax `add to cart`?

Comment: added. The problem, when I inspect the breakpoint in the ajax for add to cart, it jump out the function when reached the `data: $(...` section

Comment: I pretty sure is the `var clink = getParameterByName('clink');
if(clink != '')
{
    $("div.options input[name^='option']").val(clink);
}`
is making the problem, because once I remove this code. The page work normally. How possible this link of code is breaking the ajax?

Comment: getParameterByName  ; is it a custom method? I have not seen JavaScript inbuilt method like this. Also, I did not find clink as value to name attribute in the link of website you have provided...

Comment: @Akki619 I has added the custom method, that method is grabbing the value of the query string "clink"

Comment: var matches = regExp.exec(selected_value);
  $("span.price").text(matches[1]);         // this line is breaking matches is null

Comment: Hi @Akki619, I know that line of code is having null issue, but it is not the main problem of making the POST 404. I removed the span.price code also still having the issue.

Comment: @TomKim from debuging your website, it appears the server responding with  content-type: text\html and your ajax call is expecing JSON. Cound you set the response's Content-type: application/json on server side.

Comment: @TomKim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594326/jquery-ajax-returning-404-error-when-passing-url-as-post-data might help you

Comment: @TomKim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760538/ajax-call-to-php-script-returns-404-error might also help; its a hack

Comment: @Akki619 I had added header content-type, it seem not the solution for that. I also attached I am using Chrome REST client to send the parameter. It seem like not the script issue.

Comment: can you execute run the test scenario post disabling a firewall if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this POST 404 issue is due to Hosting Server Security Policy.
Once they disable the **mod_security** for me then the error no more.

Nothing do with the script.
Thank you so much for you all reply.
Thanks!